# Webpack 4: recompile scss takes 3+ seconds

Tags: webpack, sass

Running webpack-dev-server with hot reload, every time I change an scss file, it takes 3+ seconds to recompile, while js/html only takes less than 1 second to recompile. I couldn't figure out why.

Here is my config:

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./webpack.entry.js",
        style: "./app/scss/main/app.scss"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                        cacheDirectory: true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./app/html/index.html"
        })
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    }
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist",
        port: 9000,
        hot: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            url: false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    mode: "development"
});
```

app.scss is a bunch of scss imports, which can lead to another bunch of scss imports.

```
@import "../base";
@import "../layout";
@import "../modules";
@import "../state";
@import "../3rdparty";

/* components */
@import "../../component/footer/footer";
@import "../../component/switcher/switcher";
@import "../../component/header/header";
@import "../../component/dropdown/dropdown";
@import "../../component/lgntabset/lgntabset";
@import "../../component/lgnprogressstep/lgnprogressstep";
@import "../../component/lgnwizard/lgnwizard";
@import "../../component/lgnslider/lgnslider";
@import "../../component/lgndropdown/lgndropdown";
@import "../../component/lgnmodal/lgnmodal";
@import "../../component/calendar/weeklycalendar/calendarwidget";
```

How can I improve my scss recompile time?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a known issue: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/296, and there is not a lot you can do. Your configuration is correct.

There is an alternative https://github.com/yibn2008/fast-sass-loader, which claims to be 5~10 times faster. I don't have any experience with it, but maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something similar to `create-react-app`'s [setup](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc):

1. Running `node-sass-chokidar --watch` as a separate process, which will generate css files every time I modify scss files.
2. In JS and Webpack config, reference to the generated CSS files.

This reduces the re-compile time to ~1 second, which is better than `fast-sass-loader` (~2 secs).

**UPDATE:**

If you don't need to resolve `URL()` and `@import`, just use `raw-loader`, which reduces my re-compile to just around 0.5 second!